# Pointer to struct defined in another file

Tags: c++, struct

Is it possible to point to a struct which was defined in another file from within a class?

I tried it like in the code below but get this error:

> cannot convert 'main()::list*' to 'entry::list*' in assignment

main.cpp:

```
#include "entry.h"
#include <vector>

int main()
{

struct list
{
    std::vector<entry*> entryVector;
    int temp;
};

list A;
entry B;

B.ptrToStruct = &A;


return 0;
}
```

entry.h:

```
#ifndef ENTRY_H
#define ENTRY_H
#include <string>

class entry
{
public:

    struct list; //prototype does not work

    std::string text;
    struct list* ptrToStruct;

};

#endif // ENTRY_H
```

I also tried to write the prototype like this:

```
struct main::list;
```

That didn't work either because "'main' has not been declared".

Comment: First a little note about your terminology: A *prototype* is a forward declaration of a function. What you are doing in your `entry` class is simply forward declaring the `entry::list` class. Then about your problem: No you can't access symbols declared or defined locally in a function from another scope.

Comment: BTW, it is a bit unusual to have items cross link to each other. If each `entry` is owned by a `list`, why does it have to keep track of which list it belongs to? Adding and removing entries will be extra complicated.

Comment: It is for a settings menu. The entries dont change during runtime.
 I need the ptrToStruct to point to the submenu of that menu entry. 

So my struct is my list which holds a vector of entries. Some of those entries have a sublists. Thats why I need the pointer. The struct also holds an int which saves the selected entry.

I have a feeling that this is not the best way to do it. Im open for hints!

Answer (score 2):

This is about scope. When you declare `list` inside `entry` that is a new type `entry::list`.

If you want a global type `list` you should move the `struct list;` to the global scope outside the class.

You might want to do the same thing with the declaration inside `main`.

Comment: Thank you. Having global variables is bad style though, right?

Comment: Yes, global variables lead to a lot more complications than global types.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by global type?

What if I put the definition of the struct into a seperate .h file and include that for my main.cpp and entry.h. Would that be better?

Comment: Yes, that's the usual way to share a type between several sources. With "global" I mean something that is not nested inside another scope, like inside a class or a namespace.

Comment: Oh, if you put `list` and `entry` in two separate headers, they cannot both include each other (that would go round in circles). So you still need the `struct list;` for declaring a pointer to `list`.